# What are the technologies that underpin scripting languages?

Tags: web, scripting

I have to write a paper and the document given to me said the following:

**"How the technologies that underpin the scripting languages and enable their integration with the Web server have changed and how they have improved the performance of Web applications".**

I am somewhat lost. I can not really work out what i should write. **So my question is how do you understand the sentence above given the fact that the paper in general is about the evolution of Server-Side technologies and Scripting languages?** I was going to write about CGI (Common Gateway Interface) and ASP but i am not sure it is correct.

As this is my first post please forgive any mistake i did.

Comment: I'm sure there should be a different tag for this kind of stuff (like soft-question on mathoverflow). Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the best place for this question, but I'm going to answer it anyway. I'm not trying to give too many actual points for you to use here, but rather point you towards your own.

### Deconstructing the Question

This question consists of two main parts:

- How have the technologies underpinning scripting languages (and their integration with servers) **changed**,
- How has this **improved** the performance of web applications.

From this, it seems that the point of the question is to identify the **changes** and **trends** in scripting languages and (possibly, from your description of the paper in general) server-side technologies, and how this has **influenced** web applications (and their **performance**).

To tackle this kind of question, there are several things I would do:

- Define *server-side technologies* and *scripting languages*
- Identify the recent changes *between* and *within* these two (i.e compare them with themselves and each other)
- See how this has influenced *web applications*, referring to their *performance*.

### Answering the Question

For all of the question points above, I would heavily suggest using *examples.* Examples provide real-world data (if possible) and evidence to support the arguments you are giving. For example: your examples of ASP and CGI are good, but I would also add PHP (and maybe Rails). And for scripting languages, JavaScript is the main player.

From examples, I would analyse the different **uses** of the two categories you defined - is there any overlap between scripting languages and server-side languages and how has this changed. Throughout this, the question suggests that the main emphasis is *change*.

Now for the final part: I suggest you define both *web applications* and *performance* (hint: there is more than one type of performance), again using examples. As said, the question emphasises change and so should your examples. For instance, Facebook mostly operates on the server-side, using PHP, whereas Netflix uses AngularJS and operates more on the client-side - time is a big component here: Facebook was released much earlier, but most websites not seem to be going Netflix's way - what does this say about server-side languages in general? Why has this happened? Has this improved web applications?

Throughout this, I would suggest using any data and resources that you can find: usage statistics always make for good graphs ([e.g](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-MgralFaj860/VE1BfGMr_FI/AAAAAAAAAUI/7HfkxUHES1c/s1600/final%2Bframework.jpg)), but always cite properly and thoroughly if the content is not wholly yours.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I will consider everything you said. I would upvote you but it seems i don't have enough points yet : )